# Shortening if statement with repetition

Tags: java, if-statement

Below are some if statements for passing the pilot of a robot the correct directions based on where he in on a map and what direction he's facing. 
There a bit if repetition, but when i tried to combine conditionals the program stopped working.
Any tips for shortening this?

```
        int changeX= x-lowest.getX();
        int changeY= y-lowest.getY();
        if(changeX!=0){
            System.out.println("x changed");
            if(changeX<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'N'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','W');
            }
            else if(changeX<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'W'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','W');
            }else if(changeX<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'S'){
                robot.checkDirection('R','W');  
            }else if(changeX<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'E'){
                robot.checkDirection('R','W');  
            }else if (changeX>0 && robot.getFacing()== 'S'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','E');
            }else if (changeX>0 && robot.getFacing()== 'E'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','E');
            }else{
                robot.checkDirection('R', 'E');
            }           
        }else{
            System.out.println("y changed");
            if(changeY<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'N'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','S');
            }else if(changeY<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'W'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','S');
            }else if(changeY<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'E'){
            robot.checkDirection('R','S');  
            }else if(changeY<0 && robot.getFacing()== 'S'){
                robot.checkDirection('R','S');  
            }else if (changeY>0 && robot.getFacing()== 'S'){
            robot.checkDirection('L','N');
            }else if (changeY>0 && robot.getFacing()== 'E'){
                robot.checkDirection('L','N');
            }else{
                robot.checkDirection('R','N');
            }
        }
        //change the current cell and the x/y
        currentCell = lowest;
        x=lowest.getX();
        y=lowest.getY();

        if(goal()){
            moving=false;
            System.out.println("Goal Achieved!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _itstoped working_?

Comment: I would use one expression to work out whether the first argument to `checkDirection` should be L or R; then another expression to work out whether the second argument should be N, S, E or W.  I'd have just a single call to `checkDirection` after doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, you can at least extract the `robot.getFacing()` call so you're not repeating it.  Then you can combine some of the statements with `||`:

```
String facingDirection = robot.getFacing();

if (changeX != 0){
    System.out.println("x changed");

    if(changeX<0 && (facingDirection == 'N' || facingDirection == 'W')) {
        robot.checkDirection('L','W');
    }else if(changeX<0 && (facingDirection == 'S' || facingDirection == 'E')) {
        robot.checkDirection('R','W');
    }else if (changeX>0 && (facingDirection == 'S' || facingDirection == 'E')) {
        robot.checkDirection('L','E');
    }else{
        robot.checkDirection('R', 'E');
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("y changed");

    if(changeY<0 && (facingDirection== 'N' || facingDirection== 'W')) {
        robot.checkDirection('L','S');
    }else if(changeY<0 && (facingDirection== 'E' || facingDirection== 'S')) {
        robot.checkDirection('R','S');
    }else if (changeY>0 && (facingDirection== 'S' || facingDirection== 'E')) {
        robot.checkDirection('L','N');
    }else{
        robot.checkDirection('R','N');
    }
}
```

If you wanted to take it a step further, you could extract the parameters (eg 'R', and 'N') into two separate variables, and then set them all at the end, as well.  This would reveal some possible patterns in your data, as well as reduce the duplication of the `checkDirection` calls.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Instead of `if-else` use if statements to determine the specific direction.
> 2. Also, since you have two options for every direction 'N', 'E', 'W', 'S' have a condition for the direction and then check the x>0 or x<0

Example;

```
if(changeX!=0){
    if(getDirection() == 'N'){
          if(x>=getX()){
               System.out.println("N Direction");
          }else{
               System.out.println("S Direction");
          }
    }

    // for East
     if(getDirection() == 'E'){
          if(x>=getX()){
               System.out.println("N Direction");
          }else{
               System.out.println("S Direction");
          }
    }

    // for West
    ..........
    ..........

    // for South
    ..........
    ..........
}

// Here you remove the if-else since this will be 
// more clear and maintainable.
// If you have a huge logic, in if(){} by the time you come to else, 
// you need not go back to check what was the if condition.
// One more benefit of this is if they are isolated, and independent task, you 
// can encapsulate the logic in a method. 

if(changeY!=0){
    if(getDirection() == 'N'){
          if(x>=getX()){
               System.out.println("N Direction");
          }else{
               System.out.println("S Direction");
          }
    }

    // for East
     if(getDirection() == 'E'){
          if(x>=getX()){
               System.out.println("N Direction");
          }else{
               System.out.println("S Direction");
          }
    }

    // for West
    ..........
    ..........

    // for South
    ..........
    ..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create some kind of easy-to-read-and-modify configuration and use it, without the if statements.

A quick example just to ilustrate the concept:

```
    Map<ConfigKey, Pair<Character, Character>> config = new HashMap<ConfigKey, Pair<Character, Character>>();
    config.put(new ConfigKey("X", "DEC", "NW"), Pair.of('L', 'W'));
    config.put(new ConfigKey("X", "DEC", "ES"), Pair.of('R', 'W'));
    config.put(new ConfigKey("X", "INC", "NW"), Pair.of('R', 'E'));
    config.put(new ConfigKey("X", "INC", "ES"), Pair.of('L', 'E'));

    config.put(new ConfigKey("Y", "DEC", "NW"), Pair.of('L', 'S'));
    config.put(new ConfigKey("Y", "DEC", "ES"), Pair.of('R', 'S'));
    config.put(new ConfigKey("Y", "INC", "NW"), Pair.of('R', 'N'));
    config.put(new ConfigKey("Y", "INC", "ES"), Pair.of('L', 'N'));

    String axis   = (changeX != 0) ? "X" : "Y";
    int change    = (changeX != 0) ? changeX : changeY;
    String incDec = (change   > 0) ? "INC" : "DEC";
    String direction = (Arrays.asList('N','W').contains(facingDirection)) ? "NW" : "ES";

    Pair<Character, Character> result = config.get(new ConfigKey(axis, incDec, direction));
    robot.checkDirection(result.getLeft(), result.getRight());
```